# JWS - Retrieving ip address when a web service is called

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I'm writing (Java 6) a simple web service by implementing an interface like this:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface MyWebService {
    @WebMethod
    String helloWorld();
}
```

So, my concrete class is something like:

```
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface="xxx", 
            portName="yyy", 
            serviceName="zzz")
public class MyConcreteWS implements MyWebService {
    @Override
    public String helloWorld() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, in the method *helloWorld()* how can I retrieve any information about the caller, like for example the ip address?

I'm not developing a servlet, it's just a simple jar with a *main* method inside.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work in your case but you can try to inject the resource  `WebServiceContext` and use it to get the IP.

```
public class MyConcreteWS implements MyWebService {
   @Resource WebServiceContext wsContext;  

   @Override
    public String helloWorld() {
        MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();  
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);  
        String ip = req.getRemoteAddr(); 
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I'm retrieving a 'NullPointerException' when calling the method *getRemoteAddr()* on the object *req*.